# Issue Parsing File with YAML-CPP

Tags: yaml-cpp, c++

In the following code, I'm having some sort of issue getting my .yaml file parsed using `parser.GetNextDocument(doc);`. After much gross debugging, I've found that the (main) issue here is that my for loop is not running, due to `doc.size() == 0;` What am I doing wrong?

```
void
BookView::load()
{
  aBook.clear();

  QString fileName =
    QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Load Address Book"),
                 "", tr("Address Book (*.yaml);;All Files (*)"));
  if(fileName.isEmpty())
    {
      return;
    }
  else
    {
      try
    {
      std::ifstream fin(fileName.toStdString().c_str());
      YAML::Parser parser(fin);
      YAML::Node doc;
      std::map< std::string, std::string > entry;

      parser.GetNextDocument(doc);
      std::cout << doc.size();

      for( YAML::Iterator it = doc.begin(); it != doc.end(); it++  )
        {
          *it >> entry;
          aBook.push_back(entry);
        }

    }
      catch(YAML::ParserException &e)
    {
      std::cout << "YAML Exception caught: "
            << e.what()
            << std::endl;
    }
    }
  updateLayout( Navigating );
}
```

The .yaml file being read was generated using yaml-cpp, so I assume it is correctly formed YAML, but just in case, here's the file anyways.

```
^@^@^@\230---
-
  address: ******************
  comment: None.
  email: andrew(dot)levenson(at)gmail(dot)com
  name: Andrew Levenson
  phone: **********^@
```

**Edit:** By request, the emitting code:

```
void
BookView::save()
{
  QString fileName =
    QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save Address Book"), "",
                 tr("Address Book (*.yaml);;All Files (*)"));
  if (fileName.isEmpty())
    {
      return;
    }
  else
    {
      QFile file(fileName);
      if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
      QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Unable to open file"),
                   file.errorString());
      return;
    }

      std::vector< std::map< std::string, std::string > >::iterator itr;
      std::map< std::string, std::string >::iterator mItr;
      YAML::Emitter yaml;

      yaml << YAML::BeginSeq;
      for( itr = aBook.begin(); itr < aBook.end(); itr++ )
    {
      yaml << YAML::BeginMap;
      for( mItr = (*itr).begin(); mItr != (*itr).end(); mItr++ )
        {
          yaml << YAML::Key << (*mItr).first << YAML::Value << (*mItr).second;
        }
      yaml << YAML::EndMap;
    }
      yaml << YAML::EndSeq;

      QDataStream out(&file);
      out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_5);
      out << yaml.c_str();
    }      
}
```

Comment: What's the `^@^@^@\230` that's starting the file? (and the `^@` that's ending it?) If `yaml-cpp` is truly emitting that, can you post your emitting code as well?

Comment: I don't know what that is, so I put up the emitting code. Maybe it has something to do with setting the Qt version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along the lines of what you thought, the problem is that you're writing using `QDataStream` but reading using plain `std::ifstream`. You need to do either one or the other.

If you want to use the `QDataStream`, you'll need to read it in as well. Check out the [doc](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdatastream.html) for more detail, but it looks like you can just grab the YAML string:

```
QDataStream in(&file);
QString str;
in >> str;
```

and then pass it to yaml-cpp:

```
std::stringstream stream; // remember to include <sstream>
stream << str; // or str.toStdString() - I'm not sure about how QString works
YAML::Parser parser(stream);
// etc.
```

The point of a `std::stringstream` is to transform your string containing YAML into a stream that the YAML parser can read.

Comment: Jesse, still nothing. I modified it so it looks like this now: http://codepad.org/zBWsUU7L and in my tests, it looks like `str` is empty.

Comment: @Andrew, can you make sure you can write a string and then read it back using the `QDataStream`?

Comment: I switched over from using QDataStream to std::ofstream, and it seems to be working.